# How to rigorously treat integrals where both the integrand and the variable of integration are vectors and there's a dot product?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, vectors, integration

First, I consider this expression to find the work done by the weight over an object close to Earth's surface: $$W_{over\ object}=\int_{\vec{y_{1}}}^{\vec{y_{2}}}\vec w \cdot d\vec y$$ $$W_{over\ object}=\int_{\vec{y_{1}}}^{\vec{y_{2}}}-mg \hat{\textbf{j}} \cdot d\vec y$$ I'm assuming both the force and displacement are in the same direction, downwards, and I develop the dot product and get the next expression: $$W_{over\ object}=\int_{y_{2}}^{y_{1}}mgdy$$ Because it's going downwards ($y_{2}<y_{1}$), I thought it was a good idea to switch the integration limits since the expression is a scalar now, so that the upper limit is the highest value for the integration variable. Then I get this: $$W_{over\ object}=mgy_{1}-mgy_{2}$$

Because of Newton's third law, I may find the work done by the object over *the thing that does work over the object*, which is Earth (I guess): $$W_{over\ Earth}=\int_{\vec{y_{1}}}^{\vec{y_{2}}}-\vec w \cdot d\vec y$$ $$W_{over\ Earth}=\int_{\vec{y_{1}}}^{\vec{y_{2}}}+mg \hat{\textbf{j}} \cdot d\vec y$$ Again, I assume displacement is downwards, thus $y_{2}<y_{1}$: $$W_{over\ Earth}=\int_{y_{2}}^{y_{1}}-mgdy$$ $$W_{over\ Earth}=-mgy_{1}+mgy_{2}$$
If we let $U_{1}=mgy_{1}$ and $U_{2}=mgy_{2}$, we have: $$W_{over\ object}=-W_{over\ Earth}=U_{2}-U_{1}=\Delta U$$

In order to make this scenario more general: $$F_{over\ object}dx=W_{over\ object}$$ $$-F_{over\ object}dx=-W_{over\ object}=dU$$ $$F_{over\ object}=-\frac{dU}{dx}$$ Changing notation a bit: $$F(x)=-\frac{dU(x)}{dx}$$

After all this, what I've done seems to work, but I don't think it's rigorous at all. How can I approach this kind of problem more appropriately? More specifically, how can I treat an integral where the integrand is a vectorial function (namely, a force function), and the variable of integration is a vector as well? I think the core of my problem is treating the dot product itself when integrating, in order to find the work done by a conservative force function over a displacement interval and its associated potential energy function, with a vectorial approach.

In this sense, I have doubts regarding the derivation of the potential energy function for this particular case and how to obtain it by using a more mathematically rigorous approach.

Comment: This lacks clarity and focus. Stating _I need help on how to treat vectors appropriately for any situation...as well as on how to determine the result of the dot product by interpreting the direction of both_ is not conceptual and too broad. Please edit and focus on a conceptual question.

Comment: I tried to add clarity and focus it more. I would like to learn about a "general approach" with vectors for this kind of problems. Please let me know if I need to improve anything.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. The edit still provides no conceptual question. Can you be more specific? Do you have an example of a problem where the integrand is vectorial/contains a dot/cross product? If not, there are many questions on this site that answer all your concerns. If you still cannot get a satisfactory answer, have a read of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: What about solving the example developed in the question? I mean, obtaining the same expression for the function of gravitational potential energy associated to weight in terms of the position of the object, starting from the force function provided at the beginning and the work done by it over the object. I would like to see how someone gets a similar result by using the definitions appropriately in this scenario.

Comment: You will need to edit your question asking that particular question. It seems you're asking for the derivation but using a more mathematically rigorous approach? Is that right?

Comment: It is a good question. Integrals are usually defined for a number-valued function over a range of numbers. The OP could write down the definition of an integral like that. Now we have a vector-valued function integrated over a range of vectors, and the result is a number. How do you make sense of such an integral? How would you define it?

Comment: The limits of integration in the first two equations are also vectors, and should have arrows.

Comment: The “general approach” you are looking for is to parameterize the curve over which the integral is being performed, so the the integral becomes an ordinary integral over an interval of the parameter.

Comment: @josephh Yes, my question can be thought like that. However, even though that may help to understand better how to work this type of situation, at first I was wondering if there's a way to generalize for other functions, at least at certain extent.

Comment: Ghoster thank you for the information. I'm already finding material about the topic. Would you recommend something in particular? Besides, about the integration limits, is it always necessary to consider the limits of integration as vectors as well? Is it related to mmesser314's comment?

Comment: This kind of integral is called a “[line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)”. It’s kind of a misnomer since the “line” is in general a curve. The endpoints of the curve are points in space, which one needs a position vector to specify. The endpoints are not simply numbers, until one has parameterized the curve.

Comment: Btw my answer in [A doubt in the derivation for determining the electric potential difference between concentric spherical shells](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/520068/203278) might be helpful. It’s in an electrostatics context, but it’s the same deal. See in particular the end of my answer: literally use the definition of such line-integrals, using a parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm assuming both the force and displacement are in the same direction
> . . . .

Do not make this assumption!

Let $\hat z$ be a unit vector pointing upwards.

The work done by an external force $\vec F(z) = F(z)\, \hat z$ in moving a body from position  $z_1 \hat z$ to position $z_2 \hat z$ is

$\displaystyle \int ^{z_2} _{z_1} \vec F(z)\cdot d\vec z$.

Now the next step is where a significant error is often made by trying to decide the direction of the incremental displacement $d\vec z$ relative to the force $\vec F(\vec z)$.

Do not.

Let $\vec z = dz\,\hat z$ where $dz$ is the **component** of the incremental displacement in the $\hat z$ direction.

Thus, the  work done by external force is $\displaystyle \int ^{z_2} _{z_1} F(z)\,\hat z\cdot dz\,\hat z = \int ^{z_2} _{z_1} F(z)\,dz$.

So what about the sign of $dz$?
That is taken care of by the limits of integration.

Let the component of the external force in the $\hat z$ direction be $+m\,g$, ie $\vec F(z) = +m\,g\,\hat z$, an external force pointing upwards.

After integration the work done by the external force is $mg(z_2-z_1)$.

If $z_2>z_1$ then the work done by the external force is positive and if $z_2<z_1$ then the work done by the external force is negative.

If you want to consider the work done by the gravitational force then the only thing that changes is that now $\vec F(z) = -m\,g\,\hat z$.